# Page not found in uploading image using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem about the file uploading in codeigniter, I can see the picture in the folder name "uploads", also I can see the picture name with extension in database but it cant see in page when I view source code it will say "page not found" and I don't know why.

here is my picture-> [image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: You might have permission issues with the file, or some .htaccess rules that prevents the image to be loaded. Or routes setting in your config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this- 
thanks @jtheman

check your .htaccess code and replace with new code

or

check the  image file or upload folder permission

or

check any other .htaccess files is found inside the upload folder

Comment: What was the issue then? The QA format of SO is helped if questions have clear answers. This answer is too vague to help anyone with a similar problem.